# Why the notepad is close when I run my application as scheduled task but it works when I run it manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-task-scheduler

I have a gRPC service that open the notepad when it receives the command from the client.

This gRPC service is hosted in an ASP Core application.

I have realized that when I run the ASP core application manually and I request the command, the notepad is opened and keep open.

However, if I create a scheduled task that run my ASP application, when I request to open the notepad, the notepad is opened and close it immediately. I can't see the windows, but if I open the task manager, I can see that the process starts and closes.

Why the behavior is different when I run the application directly than when I run the application as scheduled task?

This is  the code that I use to open the notepad:

```
    ProcessStartInfo miProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    miProcessStartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
    miProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    miProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

    using (Process? miProceso = Process.Start(miProcessStartInfo))
    {
        if (miProceso == null)
        {
            throw GetRpcException($"Error indeterminado al interntar ejecutar la acción {paramRequest.NombreAccion} de la aplicación {paramRequest.NombreAplicacion}.");
        }
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which user account did you specify in scheduled tasks to run your application?

Comment: I specified UserA, it is normal user to whom I give permissions to run scheduled tasks through the gpedit.msc.

Comment: Similar question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1005725/windows-10-run-an-interactive-scheduled-task-to-run-for-any-interactive-user

Comment: @KlausGütter It is not similar. I can open notead pad from a scheduled task. The problems is if I try to open from application that is started as scheduled task. So i don't open directly the notepad from the scheduled task, but I do it from my application. And my application works because if I run it directly, not as scheduled task, it works, but not if I run it as scheduled task.